# C++ inherited methods call the base class's method instead of overloaded method

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading

Given the code:

```
class A{
public:
    void callFirst()
    {
        callSecond();
    }
    void callSecond()
    {
        cout << "This an object of class A." << endl;
    }
};

class B : public A{
public:
    void callSecond()
    {
        cout << "This is an object of class B." << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    b.callFirst();

    return 0;
}
```

I get the output:

```
This an object of class A.
```

What can I do so that when I call the inherited method of the derived class, it will not, in turn, call the base class's method instead of the overloaded one, except for overloading the first method?

Comment: Make use of `override` and you'll get a compiler error here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to mark the `callSecond()` member function `virtual`, otherwise you end up with compile-time binding (vs run-time binding).

Answer (score 2):

You should make `callSecond` in class A virtual.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class A{
public:
    void callFirst()
    {
        callSecond();
    }
    virtual void callSecond()
    {
        cout << "This an object of class A." << endl;
    }
};

class B : public A{
public:
    void callSecond()
    {
        cout << "This is an object of class B." << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    b.callFirst();

    return 0;
}
```